# How do C's file I/O functions handle NUL characters?

Tags: c

Do the file input functions in standard C, like fgetc(), fgets() or fscanf(), have any problems with NUL ('\0') characters or treat them differently than other characters?

I was going to ask if I can use fgets() to read a line that may contain NUL characters, but I just realized that since that function NUL-terminates the input and doesn't return the length in any other way, it's worthless for that use anyway.

Can i use fgetc()/getc()/getchar() instead?

Comment: Reading *text* files that contain NUL characters invokes GIGO.  Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Notice that the return type of the character ones (`int`) spans a bigger range than the values available to return (a byte). There is a reason for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're reading is actually text, then you're in somewhat of an awkward situation.  `fgets` will read NULs just fine, store them in the buffer, and soldier on.  Problem is, though, you've just read in what is no longer an NTBS (NUL-*terminated* byte string) as the C library typically expects, so most functions that expect a string will ignore everything after the first NUL.  And you really don't have a reliable way to get the length, since `fgets` doesn't return it to you and `strlen` expects a C string.  (You could conceivably zero out the buffer each time and look for the last non-NUL char in order to get the length, but for short strings in big buffers, that's kinda ugly.)

If you're dealing with binary, things are a lot simpler.  You just `fread` and `fwrite` the data, and all's well.  But if you want text with NULs in it, you're probably going to end up needing your own read-a-line function that returns the length.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the file in "TEXT" mode, then you cannot read the file beyond the NULL character. However binary files can be open()ed, read() and close()d. Look up these functions and binary i/o.

Also, EOF character is set as the NULL character in a TEXT file. You can however query using fstat the size of the binary file, and read the binary data(which may include NULL character)

Comment: "Binary" and "text" modes, AFAIK, differ in exactly one way:  the system can automatically convert newlines.  It's possible (but insane) to have a NUL in a text file, and read it and everything, on every platform i've used...but you start having issues if you're trying to treat what you read as a NUL-terminated string rather than explicitly and always specifying a length.

Comment: all I am saying is to open it with "rb". fopen("filename.bin","rb"); :)

Comment: Thing is, though, if you're reading with `fgets`, the file is apparently text.  Screwy text to be sure, if it includes NULs, but text nonetheless.  Switching to binary mode is semantically incorrect if it's actually a text file.

Comment: Also, switching to binary mode won't fix any problems with `fgets`.  You'd have to use `fread`, which ignores newlines, or `fgetc` one char at a time.

Comment: @cHao you're right. He can't use fgets() fread() is the way to go. Which is why i suggested open(), read() and close(). fread() fopen() and fclose() are its close cousins(and standard)

Answer (score 0):

No, the input functions do not treat NUL differently than other characters. Since any which return an unknown number of characters use NUL termination, though, the easiest thing to do is to write your own, such as this:

```
ssize_t myfgets(char *buffer, size_t buffSize, FILE *file) {
    ssize_t count = 0;
    int character;
    while(count < buffSize && (character = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        buffer[count] = character;
        ++count;
        if(character == '\n') break;
    }
    if(count == 0 && character == EOF) return EOF;
    return count;
}
```

This function is like `fgets`, except that it returns the number of characters read and does not NUL terminate the string. If you want the string to be NUL-terminated, change the first condition in the while loop to `count < buffSize-1` and add `buffer[count] = '\0';` just after the loop.